# How to make the converters keyword of genfromtxt (numpy) work in Python 3?

Tags: python, numpy

From the [Numpy User Guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) I take the following example that uses the converters keyword to format the data

```
from io import BytesIO
convertfunc = lambda x: float(x.strip("%"))/100
data = "1, 2.3%, 45.\n6, 78.9%, 0."
names = ('i', 'p', 'n')
a = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(data.encode()), delimiter = ',', names = names, converters = {1 : convertfunc})
print(a)
```

However, this does not work in Python 3. I get an error message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacBookPro/Documents/workspace/python3/learnnumpy/importingdata.py", line 46, in <module>
    a = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(data.encode()), delimiter = ',', names = names, converters = {1 : convertfunc})
  File "/Users/MacBookPro/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1708, in genfromtxt
    for (i, conv) in enumerate(converters)]))
  File "/Users/MacBookPro/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1708, in <listcomp>
    for (i, conv) in enumerate(converters)]))
  File "/Users/MacBookPro/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1707, in <listcomp>
    zip(*[[conv._loose_call(_r) for _r in map(itemgetter(i), rows)]
  File "/Users/MacBookPro/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/_iotools.py", line 668, in _loose_call
    return self.func(value)
  File "/Users/MacBookPro/Documents/workspace/python3/learnnumpy/importingdata.py", line 43, in <lambda>
    convertfunc = lambda x: float(x.strip("%"))/100
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

How to make this work and as a matter of fact, why does it fail exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the string literal in your `convertfunc` to a byte-string by changing from `"%"` to `b"%"` or `"%".encode()`

The reason for this is that in Python 3 strings are unicode by default, whereas in Python 2 strings are bytes by default.